# Why isn't Haskell's Data.Vector an instance of Traversable?

Tags: haskell

Don't understand, if Data.Map is and [] is. I found this out while wondering why I need `Data.Vector.mapM` for vectors and `Data.Traversable.mapM` for maps.

Comment: Be sure to click the checkbox underneath the best answers to your questions. You've gotten a number of replies over the past few days, and it's important to close them out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are [orphan instances](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Orphan_instance) on [hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-instances).

Comment: Which, if you look at the source, is basically `fmap fromList . traverse f . toList`, modulo some implementation details and whatnot.

Comment: For general questions of that form, your first stop should be the Haskell wiki. http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Orphan_instance

Comment: Added @Daniel's link to the answer, to make things a bit easier.